# (Visual)SVN ignore files by Regex

Tags: svn, visualsvn

I need to exclude files with the following pattern:

ProjectFoo.Data[0-9]{14}.lgp

How can I use RegEx for (Visual)SVN ignore list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The subversion ignore list doesn't support regular expressions. They are implemented as glob/file patterns.

These patterns don't support the {14} repeat construct.

The pattern

```
ProjectFoo.Data[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].lgp
```

should do what you ask, but I would recommend using something like ProjectFoo.Data[0-9]*.lgp as that would be 'good enough'.

Answer (score 2):

As the file looks like an LLBLGen Pro project backup file, you can force llblgen pro to store backup files into a separate folder (See preferences: default backup folder), e.g. .\Backup. This way you can exclude that folder in svn and you're done :)

Comment: Frans,

I am just astound by finding you answering this question... How do you find the time to develop LLBLGen, monitor the LLBLGen forum AND scan stackoverflow.com for little thingies!

I wish one day I had that time... Or found the same loophole for time travelling.. 

Thanks!

Comment: Heh :) Well, I registered to stackoverflow 1 day ago, and was just browsing some questions, trying out the tag filtering stuff, and my eye caught the .lgp suffix. Immediately I recognized the problem, and knew the answer :D. So call it 'just luck' ;) (oh and fast typing helps ;))

Answer (score 0):

Some basic advice for how to use the other answers on this page with TortoiseSVN backed by VisualSVN Server. You can manually add an svn:ignore property to the folder. Bert's glob/file advice for the patterns works well there (I went with the "good enough" [0-9]* myself). [More info here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html).

Navigate to the folder you want and right click | TortoiseSVN | Properties | New | Advanced. Choose a Property Name of svn:ignore and then enter your glob/file patterns on separate lines in the value box.