# How do I ignore a file/directory with a space in it with a (tortoise) SVN ignore pattern?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I'm trying to add the directory with a space in it:

```
Static Debug
```

to my SVN ignore pattern.

However, spaces are used to separate different directories (so the above ignore pattern would be interpreted as two files to ignore -- Static and Debug)

I've tried adding

```
Static%20Debug
```

and

```
"Static Debug"
```

and

```
Static\ Debug
```

with no luck

And apparently I can't ignore by [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358764/visualsvn-ignore-files-by-regex).

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Related to [Doug T.'s Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847051/how-do-i-ignore-a-file-directory-with-a-space-in-it-with-a-tortoise-svn-ignore/6847207#6847207), I played around with this a bit.

Instead of using ?, you can specify an exclusion range with [] by putting a ^ at the front.

```
ignore[^A-Za-z0-9]this
```

If I have an "ignore this" and a "ignore0this", the one with the space will be ignored, but not the one with the 0.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `A-Za-z` in the pattern?

Answer (score 3):

I found [this documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html#tsvn-dug-ignore-glob) in the tortoise manual. According to it

> [...]
>
> Matches any one of the characters enclosed in the square brackets. Within the brackets, a pair of characters separated by “-” matches any character lexically between the two. For example [AGm-p] matches any one of A, G, m, n, o or p.

<strike>So I can simply do</strike>

```
Static[ ]Debug
```

which works

Ok that actually DOESN'T WORK for whitespace in my version of Tortoise

What works is using

> ?
>
> Matches any single character.

which lets me do

```
Static?Debug
```

which unfortunately also matches stuff like StaticADebug. But this is good enough to do the trick.

Comment: Nice way to leverage the pattern matching brackets to do the job effectively.

Comment: @Edwin, I was wrong. [ ] didn't work. I must have confused my results with the ? test I did. I wish it DID work. Tortoise doesn't seem to provide anyway of escaping a space character and always sees it as a separator.

Comment: too bad.  It would have been an elegant hack.  Have you tried double and triple escaping the space?  Sometimes the name gets evaluated in a shell, which strips the first backslash.  I've had success in other tasks with items similar to Static\\\ Debug, etc.

Comment: Another item to consider is that maybe the double quotes need backslashes.  Not that they should require them; but, perhaps the processing around the name isn't very careful in preserving them, and they get stripped along the way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's a **newline** separated list. It even says so when you hover the mouse on the text box. I've just tried the name as-is and it works as expected:

```
Static Debug
```

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: mine says "Separate the patters with a space." (if you do global ignore pattern)

Comment: @crashmstr - Weird... See my screen-shot.

Comment: yes, you are in the *property* for something. That does indicate newline delimited. Not sure, but I think the original post is for global ignore patterns, and those are space delimited.

Comment: @crashmstr - You are right, I thought it was about editing the `svn:ignore` property of the parent directory, but the question clearly said *global ignore patterns* for all working copies. I misread it.