# Using regular expressions in findstr

Tags: regex, svn, hook, findstr

I'm trying to implement a hook script in Subversion, using `findstr` with a regular expression. The intent is to enforce the inclusion of an entry in the log message that matches the format used by our issue tracking tool (Atlassian JIRA). Our issues each consist of 4 to 6 capital letters and 2 to 4 numerals, separated by a hyphen (e.g., "TEST-554" or CMMGT-392"). Per instructions in the Subversion documentation, I've created a batch file to check the log message for a correctly-formatted entry, using the regex

`findstr ([A-Z]{3,6}\-[0-9]{2,4}) > nul`

I've tested the regex in a number of testing tools and it seems to work, but when I run it as part of the hook script, it fails to return a match. As a sort of "control", I tried using the regex

`findstr ...... > nul`

and was able to find a match. Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: i thing it is the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/358764/1176601 - `{}` are not supported...

Comment: Thanks, deathApril - that may well have been part of the problem; thanks to bonsaiviking's answer, below, I was able to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findstr` requires the `/R` option to use regular expressions, but it doesn't support extended regular expressions, so things like counts (`{3,6}`) don't work. Also, zero-or-one matches (`?`) don't work, so doing what you want will get pretty verbose. Also, English Windows collation means that `[A-Z]` matches 'A', 'b', 'B', 'z', and 'Z', but not 'a'. Here's something that might work:

```
findstr /R "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9][0-9] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

This incredibly verbose command may exceed the maximum command length of the shell (haven't checked), but basically does what you want by containing a separate match for each of the permutations of letter and number counts. That's another odd thing about `findstr`: unless you use the `/C` option, spaces in your match string will be used to separate it into individual match expressions.

If you have any option besides `findstr` such as PowerShell, Python, or even VBScript, I would suggest you use it. Good luck!

EDIT: Here's the Perl one-liner I used to generate the above command:

```
perl -le 'BEGIN{$\=" "}for $x (3..6){for $y (2..4){print join("","[",A..Z,"]") x $x, "-", "[0-9]" x $y}}'
```

Comment: So, what's the superlative form of "verbose" - "verbose-est"? Whatever it is, _you win_, bonsaiviking. Sadly, it _is_ too long, but it **did** start me down the right track. I found that the linkage between SVN and JIRA _is not_ case-sensitive, so I replaced `[ABCD...]` with `[A-Z]` throughout. As long as the user enters a validly formatted JIRA number, the commit goes through and the link to JIRA occurs.